После синонимизации в связанных метках сохраняется ссылка на синоним с каким-то количеством вопросов
Если выбрать метку slider, то в сайдбаре справа будет ссылка на синоним слайдер. Это не поведение всех синонимов (можно проверить на карусель или swiper.js), не связано кэшем браузера (проверено в режиме инкогнито) и не ссылка на старую метку (там было около 102 вопросов).
При переходе перекидывает правильно на правильную метку slider, но как бы с 2-мя метками slider и slider:







Видимо, это объясняется фразой «Пока без объединения»

Скорее всего, дело в кешировании. Сейчас в связанных метках такого не наблюдается.

@αλεχολυτ у меня по-прежнему [slider] со [слайдер] в связанных метках. Но после комментария andreymal я посчитала, что так и должно быть и вопрос закрыт.

В приватном режиме у меня отобразилось тоже. Похоже, что баг вернулся. Надо постить на MSE. И лучше бы с подтверждением на других сайтах.

Запостил на MSE
